# Android Device Manager Ringing Wrong Device

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, android-device-manager

I have both a Samsung S5 phone and a Samsung Galaxy tablet. When I log into Android Device Manager both these devices are listed however when I try to ring my phone it rings the tablet. If I ring the tablet, it also rings the tablet. The phone is about a month old and this is the first time I have played around with the Android Device Manager so I don't know if it ever worked properly or not. I also don't know if the location is tracking my phone or the tablet because they are both in my house. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by removing the device from Device Manager, restarting, then adding it back. Now each device rings appropriately. Hope this helps someone in the future.